# Does H2OAutoML handle hyperparamter optimization?

Tags: h2o, automl

I know that there are different methods in H2O such as H2OGridSearch, H2ORandomSearch to perform hyperparameter optimization. However, is there a way to include hyperparameter optimization method when we use H2OAutoML to train many models at once? Does it already include it as a default?
Any inputs would be beneficial.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, H2O's AutoML does also hyperparameter optimization. It mainly does random grid search. From the [docs](http://docs.h2o.ai/h2o/latest-stable/h2o-docs/automl.html#random-grid-search-parameters):

> AutoML performs a hyperparameter search over a variety of H2O
> algorithms in order to deliver the best model. In the table below, we
> list the hyperparameters, along with all potential values that can be
> randomly chosen in the search. If these models also have a non-default
> value set for a hyperparameter, we identify it in the list as well.
> Random Forest and Extremely Randomized Trees are not grid searched (in
> the current version of AutoML), so they are not included in the list
> below.
>
> Note: AutoML does not run a grid search for GLM. Instead AutoML builds
> a single model with lambda_search enabled and passes a list of alpha
> values. It returns only the model with the best alpha-lambda
> combination rather than one model for each alpha.